# reg expression replace not replacing space-dash-space

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to strip out any non-alphanumeric characters and also replace any whitespace with an underscore.

myString = myString.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, '').replace(" ", "_");

This almost it, but it still fails in one case:

```
12th Madison - 100
```

Becomes

```
12th_Madison  100
```

What I would like is this:

```
12th_Madison_100
```

Comment: What is your expected answer?

Comment: see edit to OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second replace method only replaces the first occurrence of white space since you passed a string as pattern, see the [docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Parameters); If you want to replace globally, you can use regex `/\s+/g` or `/\s/g` depending on if you want to collapse consecutive white spaces:

```js
let myString = "12th Madison - 100"

myString = myString.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, "_");

console.log(myString)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to include the space in

> /[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g

?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
result = subject.replace(/[^\w]+/g, "_");
```

`[^\w]` ...  Match a single character that is not a word character (ASCII letter, digit, or underscore only)